# Couldn't able to import environment variable for django settings.py for sending email in linux ubuntu system

Tags: python, django

When I specify EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD directly email send properly but if try to get using os.environ it is throwing following error `(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError l26sm20714449pgn.46 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')`. I have tried to add variables in .bashrc and .bash_profile but it didn't worked. What I have tried shown below. can anyone help me this please.

### settings.py

variables shown below.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'name@gmail.com'
# EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '123456789'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
print('variable :',os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER'))
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

### .bashrc

This file is in the same directory where settings.py exist.

```
import os
export EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'name@gmail.com'
export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '9538913650'
```

### main

below lines I have tried in terminal both in global and vertual envirnment.

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER=name@gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=123456789
```

### using python comand

code shown below.

```
import os
os.environ.set('EMAIL_HOST_USER') = 'name@gmail.com'
os.environ.set('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD') = 12345678
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `os.environ.get('...')` - it silently fails when the environment variable is missing. Use `os.environ['...']` instead.

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER']
print('variable :',os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER'])
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD']
```

Next, the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` will only work if you are running Django from a shell that has sourced those files. Remove the `import os`, it is not Python.

Next, you still need the `export` in your shell if you set the variables before running Django.

```
export EMAIL_HOST_USER=name@gmail.com
export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=123456789
```

If you want to set the environment variables in Python, then treat `os.environ` as a dict instead of trying to call `.set(...)`.

```
import os
os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER'] = 'name@gmail.com'
os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'] = 12345678
```

Finally, even if this works on your local box, it might stop working when you deploy on a server with a different IP address. Every week I see questions on Stack Overflow where users are struggling to send emails from Django using gmail. I usually suggest that they think about using a different email provider.

Comment: Thankyou Alasdair, I am getting key error when I do runserver even I set variable. I have used `os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER'] = 'name@gmail.com'

Comment: I placed code here /home/user/.bashrc and tried by creating .bash_profile and adding  variable in it.

Comment: You can't put Python code in a `.bashrc` file. It would need to go in a Python file that is loaded before the settings are loaded, e.g. in `manage.py`.

Comment: I have set the code (os.environ....) in seetings.py but variable I specified in .bashrc

Comment: But `os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER'] = 'name@gmail.com'` is Python code you can’t put it in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Before you run `manage.py runserver`, run `env`. If you don’t see the variables in the output, then your `bashrc` file hasn’t worked.

Comment: I kept opened environment variables directory in another terminal as you told django  works with it only when it is run through shell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `decouple` library? Here is a good example: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html

Usage:

```
# settings.py
from decouple import config

EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
```

Then create a .env file (and add it to .gitignore if needed):

```
# .env (save in the same folder as manage.py)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_email@some_url.some_extension'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wasted another 2 hours... you only need to restart your computer and it will work with your original code

Comment: `Just wasted another 2 hours` Do you mean by that, that you tried all solutions posted here without success? And then you did reboot? Because in that case, it means that at least one of the solutions worked, and rebooting did activate it. Or are you saying that one does not need any of these solutions at all?

Comment: Right, I did not need any of these solutions. My code, which was the same as the one in the question, worked after rebooting. Printing the environment variables already returned the correct strings before rebooting but for some reason it did not work when trying to reset the password. After rebooting it worked without changing the code.